# NextCloud Android App: NC Passwords, cannot get past "Granting"

Tags: android, passwords, nextcloud

I am trying to get the NC Passwords app to work for nextcloud passwords. I have my nextcloud snap appliance on a Raspberry Pi 4b/8GB system, and I have it behind an Nginx reverse proxy, with a LetsEncrypt SSL cert securing it. However, I cannot get past "Granting" when trying to log into NC Passwords for the first time. I am hoping I am not the only person who experienced this, and knows of some solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I feel foolish.

If someone else runs into this, force-stop the NC Passwords app on your Android device, then do a "Clear Data" on it. Then try again. it works.